# How to disable data.table names at the bottom?

Tags: r, printing, data.table

I am running Rstudio 0.99.489 and R-3.2.3 on Windows 7

How can I avoid printing V1 and N at the bottom of the data ?

```
options(datatable.print.nrows = Inf)
dt <- data.table(sample.int(2e3, 1e4, T))
print(dt[ , .(.N), V1])

...
1980:  419  1
1981:  898  2
1982: 1260  1
        V1  N
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can manipulate print of an object as a regular character vector.

```
library(data.table)
options(datatable.print.nrows = Inf)
dt = data.table(sample.int(2e3, 1e4, T))
myprint = function(x){
    prnt = capture.output(print(x))
    cat(prnt[-length(prnt)], sep="\n")
}
myprint(dt[ , .(.N), V1])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternative to consider. Since `data.table`s are enhanced `data.frame`s, why not just use the `print` method for `data.frame`s? That way, you get both printing all the rows of the inputs, but without the column names appearing at the bottom as well.

For instance, the following dataset is sufficient to demonstrate the behavior of printing names at the bottom.

```
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.table(sample(21, 1000, TRUE)) ## Sufficient to demonstrate behavior
dt[, .N, by = V1]                        ## Shows the names at the bottom
```

You can manually specify the `print.data.frame` method, like this:

```
print.data.frame(dt[, .N, by = V1])      ## Specify use of data.frame print method
```

Or, since you're not printing something that affects your original `data.table`, you could also do something like this:

```
setDF(dt[, .N, by = V1])[]                ## dt stays a `data.table`
```